# having multiple php file upload in a form keeps carrying first file name to other uploads

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload

Right i have a form that connects to a php script. With in the form there is multiple inputs such as text, checkbox, dropdown etc. However i also have 3 upload slots for 3 images that get uploaded to a img folder and i just grab the name to store in a mysql database along with the form.

here is the form.

```
    <form method="post" action="scripts/AddProduct.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"><table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Category</td>
            <td><label><select id="pro_catagory" name"pro_catagory">
              <?php echo $result; ?>
              </select>
            </label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Subcatagory</td>
            <td><label>
              <select name="pro_subcategory" id="pro_subcategory">
              <option value="Hats">Hats</option>
              </select>
            </label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Details</td>
            <td><textarea name="pro_details" cols="" rows=""></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Size</td>
            <td>
            S
            <input type="hidden" name="pro_size" value="0" /> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="pro_size" value="1" />
            M
            <input type="hidden" name="pro_size_m" value="0" /> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="pro_size_m" value="1" />
            L
            <input type="hidden" name="pro_size_l" value="0" /> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="pro_size_l" value="1" />
        </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Colour</td>
            <td><label>
              <input type="text" name="pro_colour" id="colour"/>
            </label></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td align="right">1st Image</td>
            <td><label>
              <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            </label></td>
          </tr>     

          <tr>
            <td align="right">2nd Image</td>
            <td><label>
              <input type="file" name="filee" id="filee" />
            </label></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <td align="right">3rd Image</td>
            <td><label>
              <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />
            </label></td>
          </tr>
<tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Item Now" />
        </label></td>
      </tr> </table></form>
```

(I have shortend down the script so its only examples of what are in the form). Their are a total of 21 options in the form.

Foloowing this the php file AddProduct.php.

```
    <?php 
    //File Upload 1
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {

      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br><br>";




      if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          }
        }
    //File Upload 2
    if ($_FILES["filee"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["filee"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["filee"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["filee"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["filee"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["filee"]["tmp_name"] . "<br><br>";

      if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["filee"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["filee"]["name"] . " already exists. " . "<br><br>";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filee"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["filee"]["name"]);
          }
        }
    //File Upload 3
     if ($_FILES["file3"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file3"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file3"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file3"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file3"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file3"]["tmp_name"] . "<br><br>";

      if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file3"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file3"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file3"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file3"]["name"]);
          }
        }

  //Rest of php to get the posted values (all still work)
?>
```

My problem is that when its submitted the name of file (image 1) is then followed through to filee and file3 so the output ends like:

```
Upload: testing.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 684.8818359375 kB
Stored in: C:\wamp\tmp\php41FF.tmp

testing.jpg already exists. Upload: 
Type: 
Size: 0 kB
Stored in: 

already exists. 

Upload: 
Type: 
Size: 0 kB
Stored in:
```

thanks for any help in advance

EDIT: this is var_dump

```
array (size=3)
  'file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '2Fourk. RV2.jpg' (length=15)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php4FD7.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 701319
  'fileField2' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '2Fourk.jpg' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php4FD8.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 938840
  'fileField3' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'fiverrgigs.png' (length=14)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php4FE9.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 18322
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_FILES)` show?

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to match your description of the problem. The output shows that the `filee` and `file3` uploads are empty, not copies of `file`.

Comment: I actually just tried your script and in my environment (XAMPP) it works. The script distinguish all 3 images and shows their names.

Comment: @barmar see the edit for the var dump.

Comment: @DanielStutz its not for me :(

Comment: got it thats to the both of you. for sume reason the names havent updated on the code and so i just renaimed the names and it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @drive235 makes a good suggestion

I made this short script. very dirty. but maybe it helps you, since you use many lines of scripts. Sometimes it is easier with less.

it iterates trough the $_FILES Array and shows the various image information.

```
foreach($_FILES as $v){
          echo "<br />Upload: " . $v["name"]. "<br>";
          echo "Type: " .$v["type"] . "<br>";
          echo "Size: " . ($v["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
          echo "Stored in: " . $v["tmp_name"] . "<br><br>";
    var_dump($v);
}
```

Comment: glad, when it helps you

Answer (score 1):

**Just a suggestion**. When you upload multiple files you should (well, I would) use one multiple upload file input.

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple/>
```

And then in php work with this as with array.

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
   for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
          echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] . "<br>";
      }
      else {
          //do something with $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
      }
   }
}
```

The code will be shorter and you will do all things at "once".

Comment: would i be able to grab each file name and put them into individual images? cheers

Comment: Sure, actually this is filename: `$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]`. Where $i is index of uploaded file. In your case $i will be 0, 1 and 2, since you will have 3 files.

Comment: This is a better way for sure, but less browser support.

Comment: Thats a lot i will have a go at incorporate it as it looks easyer and smaller. thanks a lot :)